# Can't access web archived rewritten URLs using javascript

Tags: javascript, webarchive

I'm trying to get some href properties using javascript on a web-archived page, but the result I'm getting is different from what's actually in the page. I think it'll be easier to explain what I mean with an actual example, so, for the following web-archived page:

https://web.archive.org/web/20090101161506/http://www.sapo.pt/

There's a "mail" button on the right side:
[image: mail button]

If you inspect it with the browser you get the following element:

```html
<a 
  onclick="lk('/mail','tools');toolTabSwap('mailBox',false);return(false);" 
  href="https://web.archive.org/web/20090101161506/http://mail.sapo.pt/" 
  id="bmailBox" 
  class="widget_btn"
>
    <div>Mail</div>
</a>
```

Notice how the href is pointing towards web.archive.org

However, when I try to get this href value using javascript, what I get is different:

[image: console output]

Now, I know that web archives rewrite the original hrefs to point towards their archived version, and it's clearly what's happening here. What I don't understand is why I can't get the rewritten URL via javascript, and instead it's showing me the href from before it's been rewritten.

What's going on here? How can I get the href to the web-archived version rather than the original link?

**Edit:**

Something I want to clarify: I'm not looking to follow the URL, I just want to use JS to get the full URL from the web archive, **including the `web.archive.org` domain and the timestamp**.

For the example link, I want to find a way to get this:

`https://web.archive.org/web/20090101161506/http://mail.sapo.pt/`

But all I'm getting is this:

`http://mail.sapo.pt/`

Comment: You probably need to change it from the backend. Meaning where the page source is coming from. Or add the JS to update the link on page load `document.querySelector('#bmailBox').href = "https://mail.sapo.pt/"`. Some more context would be appreciated!

Comment: `return false;` in the `onclick` attribute prevents following the link when you click on it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick replies. All I want is to get the web-archived version of the URL via javascript, I was expecting that doing `document.querySelector('#bmailBox').href` would give me `https://web.archive.org/web/20090101161506/http://mail.sapo.pt/` but instead what I'm getting is `https://mail.sapo.pt/`. I'm not actually trying to click on the link, just get the href.

Comment: Regarding why you're seeing that in the console, there's probably JavaScript that rewrites the `href` dynamically. Looks like it removes the `https://web.archive.org/web/<timestamp>/` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

when you open the URL `(https://web.archive.org/web/20090101161506/http://mail.sapo.pt/)` it gives you a 302 HTTP status code.

the status code 302 is a temporary redirect, which means the `https://web.archive.org/web/20090101161506` redirects you to `http://mail.sapo.pt/`. javascript will follow the redirect and it reaches http://mail.sapo.pt/ and then it will receive the 200 HTTP status code and that's what you will see. the scenario is like this:

request --> web.archive.org (redirect user to)--> mail.sapo.pt

you might ask why websites use redirection?
URL redirection is done for various reasons:

- for URL shortening
- to prevent broken links when web pages are moved
- to allow multiple domain names belonging to the same owner to refer to a single website.
- to guide navigation into and out of a website

if you want to get the original href, I suggest you to use jQuery:

import jQuery using CDN or whatever method you like:

- add the CDN script link in the head of your HTML file

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

- select the href of the `<a>` element and you can do whatever you want with it without getting redirect:

```js
var hrefValue = $('#bmailBox').attr('href');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I did notice that the link was towards a 302 status. However I think that's not the issue because it happens even the link is towards a 200 status, for example, the link with selector `#newsitems > li:nth-child(1) > a`, when you get the href via javascript you still only get the original url, not the `web.archive.org/web/<timestamp>/<original url>`. I'm not trying to open the URL, what I'm interested in is the full web archived link, including the timestamp.

Comment: I tried loading jQuery and I still don't get the full link :(

Comment: thats a little wired for me cause i test this via jQuery and this is what it gave me when i had the `<a>` tag in my html file:

i get this from hrefValue variable: `https://web.archive.org/web/20090101161506/http://mail.sapo.pt/`

Comment: which web browser do you use? or which jQuey version are you using?
it's really important which jQuery version you are using cause in that case the code will be different. test it with version 3.7.1 and let me know if the result is different in the latest version

Comment: I use Chrome, or Brave (which is built on top of chrome so it shouldn't matter). What i did was load jQuery using the console using the following commands:
 ```var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script  = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js';
script.media = 'all';
head.appendChild(script)```
Then when I used it to get the href i still got `http://mail.sapo.pt/`

Comment: yeah, there's no problem with the browser as you said. but do you think JavaScript is following the redirect? or the href attribute of the element is changing before you grab it with JavaScript?

Comment: I think this is related to the wombat.js library that dynamically rewrites links on web archives, it must be overriding the behavior of Element.href. Something I've noticed is that on the console, if you try to get `document.querySelector('#bmailBox').attributes.href` it'll display the Attr object with the correct web-archived link: `href="https://web.archive.org/web/20090101161506/http://mail.sapo.pt/"` However, when you try to get the string value via `attributes.href.toString()` you get `'[object Attr]'` and if you try doing `attributes.href.value` we go back to `'http://mail.sapo.pt/'`

Comment: when you use the console, it means all javascript library is loaded into the DOM and as you said it looks like some javascript code is rewriting the attribute, the solution might be to the answering of the following question: 
where and how your code is executed? 
is it on the HTML page where the all JS library is loaded? or are you using something else like selenium?
if you are using it in the HTML page in which all these HTML elements and javascript libraries exist, you need to open the script tag when all content is loaded. (before the closing body tag `</body>`).

Comment: if not, i don't know how to fix this